# How to prevent react-route from re-render the whole app when changing url

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-router

I'm working on an app use react-history.
The whole app get re-rendered every time i change the URL by using:

```
props.history.location.replace(newPath);
```

That behavior make a great impact to performance.
What i want is just change the URL which update some query params so user can share the view with another one just by the url.
I wonder if there are a way to work around this problem.
Thanks for advice.

Comment: Your view is being rendered again because your url is changing. If you can keep the url same and keep your query params as a prop to the to be rendered component, then i guess it should be fine

Comment: Thanks Aseem Upadhyay, but the thing is user want to copy and paste the URL, so they can share their view with another colleague. So, i can't pass it as prop to the component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your component inside a common component where you had specified your layout. Only the body of the layout needs to be re-rendered.

```
//App.js
import Layout from "../LayoutContainer/Layout"; // where i designed the application's layout
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Router >
          <div>
            <Route path="/home" exact component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/product" exact component={Products} />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

By using this way, only the content inside the layout would be re-rendered unless the whole application.

Comment: Thanks Jeeva, but there are no common layout in our app. The layout component like navigation bar, title bar ... will be changed dynamically based on URL's path. but i only wana change the query param section.

Comment: No, the layout component like navigation bar, title bar or sidebar cannot be changed. You might have designed the layout with all these components and you would have allocated the space for rendering other components inside the body of the layout component. Each time when the URL changes, the body of the layout will be changed unless all the components in a page. You jus keep the static components in the layout. Inside the body of layout, just specify as follows **this.props.children**  which enables to render the children component when the URL changes

Comment: Hi Jeeva, the layout is not contains the content section, it is placed before the content section:
<Router>
<Route
                path={route.path}
                exact={route.exact}
                component={route.toolbar}
              /><Route
                path={route.path}
                exact={route.exact}
                component={route.main}
              />
</Router>